# VLC or MPC-HC open video folder and wait for video selection

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, media-player

In VLC or MPC-HC
is there a way (native ou a plug-in)
to open the player pointing to a specified folder,
and show all videos (thumbnails preferrably)
waiting for the user to choose one to see...

If possible when video end or stop return to
the initial thumbnail screen

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to emulate Kodi.

Comment: For example `vlc yourdirectory/* --no-playlist-autostart`. Or you can use Kodi... :) For the thumbnail I'm not sure.

Comment: why not just turn the folder to thumbnail view and double click on the files?

Comment: the "VLC.exe --no-playlist-autostart <folder>"is the solution I'm using now... I only hate it has no way to display the video thumbnails... and also when you stop a video does not return to the playlist...

Comment: I want the solution to pass through a media player (preferably that works on several OS(s)... VLC is great... I thought by now someone would had made a plugin to resolve this...